# Meetup API - get past AND upcoming events

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, meetup

The docs say that you can pass a status into the request object as follows:

Status may be "upcoming", "past" or both separated by a comma. The default is "upcoming" only

But when I pass in "past,upcoming" as the value for status, no events are returned.

How do I get past AND upcoming events?

Comment: Using postman http://i.imgur.com/VszNEtO.png

Comment: @Baumannzone how did you construct that link?